# How do I get PHPUnit 10 working in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

PHPUnit 10 has removed the `--whitelist` option, which PhpStorm automatically inserts into the "Run with Coverage" option. How do I fix this?

Error message:

> Unknown option "--whitelist"

I can't find any information online on how to fix this problem.

Comment: The issue is tracked as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71423/PHPUnit-10-whitelist-option-for-coverage-is-no-longer-supported . Check the last comment there  -- maybe that suggestion will work for you.

Comment: @LazyOne I was able to fix the issue with the info you provided, thank you. If anyone else has the problem I would also like to add that the default `phpunit.xml.dist` file also contains some deprecated options. However, PHPStorm had no problem detecting them, outlineing them, and they were simple to remove.

Comment: Great. Please post you actual/final solution as an answer (what other options you had to remove from the config file etc). You can mark the answer as Accepted in a few hours/days later: it will help others in a similar situation (accepted answer is more visible in search results).